# How do I align text in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to align some text that I put on two separate lines using return. How do I align the text? Justify under Paragraph doesn't seem to do anything. I figured "Area Type Options" might help, but that box isn't clickable. How do I align the text (both left- and right-aligned)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *must* use **Area Type** if you want a single block of text to have separate lines left and right aligned.

Area type is created by drawing a box with the **Type Tool** by click-dragging, then typing. As opposed to merely clicking somewhere with the Type Tool and typing (which is called Point Text).

---

If you have point text, then you would most likely need to split the lines so they are separate and then *manually* position the text as desired.

Point text will align *on its anchor point*. One line left and one line right will create opposing text - as if on a center pole.

---

Top line left aligned, second line right aligned....

[image]

Area Type is necessary so Illustrator can know *where* the right side is to be located. Without the defining box of Area Type, Illustrator only knows where the type anchor point is.